# SSRS Page footer does not display the correct information after the first page

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am working on a SSRS report for SQL 2005 in Visual Studio 2005 and I need to include information in the page footers from a dataset. I followed the information in the following Microsoft article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159677(v=sql.90).aspx

I setup several hidden textboxes in the body of the report to hold the aggregated dataset information I need. I then reference those textboxes in the page footer of my report.

The page footer on the first page is correct but on the rest of the report pages the text boxes are not getting the information. In my situation, I am getting the user id and date from a dataset and trying to display it on each report page in the footer.

**More details:**

In the first hidden textbox (lblDatetime) in the body I get the value from the dataset like the following:

```
=First(Fields!Date.Value, "headerData1")
```

In the second hidden textbox (lblUserID) in the body I get the value from the dataset like the following:

```
=First(Fields!UserID.Value, "headerData1")
```

I then reference the first textbox in the footer using the following:

```
=First(ReportItems!lblUserID.Value)
```

I then reference the second textbox in the footer using the following:

```
 =FormatDateTime(First(ReportItems!lblDateTime.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate)
 =FormatDateTime(First(ReportItems!lblDateTime.Value),DateFormat.LongTime)
```

I tried aggregating the dataset directly in the footer but this is not possible and causes errors.

Comment: I came up with a different solution to the one suggested in the article. 

Instead of adding hidden textboxes to my body I created global two hidden global parameters.
I set the default value using the "From Query" for those parameters to the datasets I needed to reference. I then referenced those two new global parameters instead of the textboxes. 

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a different solution to the one suggested in the article.

Instead of adding hidden textboxes to my body, I created two global hidden parameters. I set the default value using the "From Query" for those parameters to the datasets I needed. I then referenced those two new global parameters instead of the textboxes.

This fixed my issue.